# Composition of analytic and non analytic function is analytic, if and only if function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question regarding to complex functions:

Let there be $\Omega \subseteq C$ and let be  $f=u_1 +iv_1$ an analytic function in $\Omega$. And suppose that a function $g=u_2 +iv_2$ is non-analytic for every $z \in \Omega$ but does have continuous partial derivatives.
Prove that $h=f(g)$ is analytic in $\Omega$ if and only if, $f$ is a constant function in $\Omega$.

To prove that $h$ is analytic given that $f$ is constant is trivial. But for the other direction I'm stuck. I've tried Cauchy–Riemann equations and the chain rule to prove that $f'(z_0) =0 | z_0\in\Omega$, but it has not gotten me anywhere, would like some advise with explanation if possible, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverse $f^{-1}$ exists near any point $z_0$ at which $f^\prime(z_0) \neq 0$. Assuming such $z_0$ exists, near it we would have $g = f^{-1}(h)$. This would be a contradiction since $f^{-1}$ is also analytic due to Cauchy–Riemann equations and because we are given that at each point $g$ is non-analytic.

Or you can directly apply Cauchy–Riemann equations to $h = u_1(u_2, v_2) + v_1(u_2, v_2) i$, assuming $h$ is analytic.

You will obtain 
$$\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial y}, $$

$$\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x}. $$

Using Cauchy–Riemann for $f$, i.e $\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x}$,  you can rewrite this as follows
$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} & -\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x}\\ \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial  x} & \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x}  \end{pmatrix} = 0.$$

Assuming $f^\prime = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial  x} + i\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial  x} \neq 0$ at some point of $\Omega$. we will have that determinant of the above matrix is non-zero. This would mean that at this point $g$ satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equaions.

Comment: thank you for your answer, to understand your question better:

you applied the chain rule on h, correct?

there for shouldn't it be: 

$\cfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial u_2} \cfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x} $etc. ?

Comment: I meant $\frac{\partial( u_1(u_2, v_2))}{\partial x}(x, y) = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}(u_2(x, y), v_2(x, y)) \cdot \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}(x, y) + \ldots$

Comment: I think it's just a matter of how we call variables of $u_1$, so you are right too

Answer (score 1):

I suppose $g$ non-analytic for any $z \in \Omega$ means each point has a neighborhoods in which $g$ is not analytic. You also have to make the assumptions that the range of $g$ is contained in $\Omega$ so that $f\circ g$ is defined. Suppose $f'$ is not a constant. Then its zeros are isolated. If $f'(z_0) \neq 0$ then  $f$ has an analytic inverse in some open set $N$ containing $z_0$ by Open Mapping Theorem and that makes $g$ analytic in the open set $g^{-1}(N)$. This contradicts the hypothesis, so $f'$ is a constant. But then $f(z)=az+b$ fro some constants $a,b$ and analyticity of $f\circ g$ im plies that og $g$ un less $a=0$. Hence $f$ is a constant.